# NSResponder resignFirstResponder fires on wrong object

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsresponder

I have a Mac application (SDK 10.10) with some NSTextFields:

[image: Xib file]

Since I need to get notified when a text field gets and resigns focus, I subclassed NSTextField:

```
@interface MyTextField : NSTextField
@end

@implementation MyTextField

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    BOOL didBecomeFirstResponder = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"%@ didBecomeFirstResponder = %@", [self accessibilityLabel], didBecomeFirstResponder?@"YES":@"NO");
    return didBecomeFirstResponder;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    BOOL didResignFirstResponder = [super resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"%@ didResignFirstResponder = %@", [self accessibilityLabel], didResignFirstResponder?@"YES":@"NO");
    return didResignFirstResponder;
}

@end
```

When runing this code and tabbing between the 3 text fields, I get this output in the console:

```
firstField didResignFirstResponder = YES
firstField didBecomeFirstResponder = YES
secondField didResignFirstResponder = YES
secondField didBecomeFirstResponder = YES
thirdField didResignFirstResponder = YES
thirdField didBecomeFirstResponder = YES
firstField didResignFirstResponder = YES
firstField didBecomeFirstResponder = YES
secondField didResignFirstResponder = YES
secondField didBecomeFirstResponder = YES
```

Every time I hit the TAB key (or click in one of the inactive text fields), the app outputs

```
<new first responder> didResignFirstResponder = YES
<new first responder> didBecomeFirstResponder = YES
```

Shouldn't that be

```
<old first responder> didResignFirstResponder = YES
<new first responder> didBecomeFirstResponder = YES
```

???

Do I something terribly wrong here?

The documentation of `- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder` says

> Notifies the receiver that it’s been asked to relinquish its status as
>   first responder in its window.

So why gets `resignFirstResponder` called on the new first responder and not the old one?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and couldn't find a solution, so I ended up with working around it and using `textDidEndEditing()` method for the same purpose. Swift code:

`MyTextField` subclasses `NSTextField` and adds `myDelegate` property to it that should handle logic after the text field lost focus.

```
class MyTextField : NSTextField
{

/// Custom delegate with other methods than NSTextFieldDelegate.
var myDelegate: MyTextFieldDelegate? = nil;

override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    let became = super.becomeFirstResponder();
    if (became) {
        self.myDelegate?.myTextFieldDidBecomeFirstResponder(self);
    }
    return became;
}

override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    let resigned = super.resignFirstResponder();
    if (resigned) {
        self.myDelegate?.myTextFieldDidResignFirstResponder(self);
    }
    return resigned;
}

override func textDidEndEditing(obj: NSNotification) {
    super.textDidEndEditing(obj);
    self.myDelegate?.myTextFieldDidResignFirstResponder(self);
}

}
```

The protocol itself:

```
protocol MyTextFieldDelegate
{

    func myTextFieldDidBecomeFirstResponder(textField: MyTextField);

    func myTextFieldDidResignFirstResponder(textField: MyTextField);
}
```

Obviously, instead of using and calling a delegate, you could just implement your lost/gained focus logic right there (e.g. draw different border, etc).

The clue is the `textDidEndEditing()` method and it seems to work for fine when I click in another field, when I press enter or when I tab out.

Answer (score 1):

Someone on the Apple developer forums explained why it behaves like it does:

> When text fields have focus, they aren't actually the first responder. Cocoa creates a special text view, called the [field editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html), and temporarily adds it to the view hierarchy, covering the text field. It makes that text view the first responder. This text view is what handles all user interaction.

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109158#339676

### Workarounds

Overriding the [`textDidEndEditing:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfield/1399420-textdidendediting?language=objc) method (mentioned by Michał in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464108/2228559)) is the best solution, IMO.

If you don't want to subclass `NSTextField`, create a class that conforms to the [`NSTextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfielddelegate?language=objc) protocol and implements the [`controlTextDidEndEditing:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontroltexteditingdelegate/3005178-controltextdidendediting?language=objc) method. Then, set the `delegate` property of your `NSTextField` instance.

Lastly, you *could* override the [`fieldEditor:forObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419647-fieldeditor?language=objc) method of an `NSWindow` subclass. But there's literally no formal documentation for this approach (that I could find).

To learn more about the "field editor", read these articles:

- http://cocoadev.github.io/FieldEditor/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH8-BBCFEBHA
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html